# Tree DIV expand to full screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a banner with a possibility to expand it to the full screen independent on resolution.

```
<body>
    <div class="div_left"></div>
    <div class="div_middle_fixed"></div>
    <div class="div_right"></div>
</body>
```

Here is a div with a jpg placed in the center of a screen with fixed size 1000px. And I need to “expand” this banner to full screen using 2 other pics (div with dynamic size). I need one at the beginning of my fixed banner which expands dynamic to the left. And the second one at the end of my fixed banner which expands dynamic to the right.

I need this trick so the graphics of a banner has to match at the adges

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `calc()` - `.div_left, .div_right{width: calc((100% - 1000px)/2);}` to get the width. And for _banner has to match at the adges_ you can use `background-position` for those divs.

Comment: What have you got on the sides ? Something like a gradient `picture --> color` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the images as backgrounds to those divs, and so forth use this CSS attribute to keep it contained when the site is scaled:

```
background-size: contain;
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add a background-size with the following parameters
cover - Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

or

contain - Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

and
percentage - Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto"

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp